# Extract Structerd/Tabular form data by OCR Parsing

Tags: image, forms, parsing, pdf, ocr

Is any API or Templates available for extract image's structured fields data that have a table(row/columns). i want to parse a form that have a tight field structure and also check-boxes, but still i not get any useful open-source or premium apis.